# Google Cloud managed instance group issue with plesk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, load-balancing, plesk

I'm losing my mind over this so i thought I would ask about it. I have a VM instance that I was asked to put into managed instance group so that later on we can stuff like load balancing and Cloud armor.

This Vm instance has plesk panel that is configured with a website on it which is configured with a public domain to point to it.
I shut down the vm instance, create an image, then create instance template and finally create the managed instance group. The problem is that the instances that launch will have their internal and external ip addresses different then the original vm obviously so none of them will work until I ssh inside the vm instances and do some repairs like : **Plesk repair all** and that doesn't fix everything.

Essentially lets say original vm has internal ip : **11.11.11.1** and external ip : **20.20.20.1**
when i create the managed instance group the first vm launching from the template will have 
internal ip  : **11.11.11.2** and external ip  **20.20.20.2**
but the config for plesk was setup for the first set of ips, so every instance created will be usesless as a webserver till they are fixed

Ive watched a lot of the tutorials on Managed vm instance groups, but none of them solve this issue. I'm trying to create a managed instance group of webservers that will go into a load balancer later.The tutorials online show just some simple start up script with one page being load balanced...
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I do not have much experience with Plesk. Suggestions: 1) Configure an HTTP load balancer with a global public IP address, domain name and SSL certificate. 2) Use Unmanged Instance Groups so that you can configure Plesk on each VM instance with private IP addresses that do not change. 3) In Plesk go to Tools & Settings -> IP Addresses. Set the Public IP Address to the HTTP Load Balancer public IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's what I'm currently planning to do as I coulnd not find a way for it work with managed group instances

Comment: I did set it up with unmanaged but I'm stil trying the managed approach. One way I thought about was creating a template and running a startup script to midfy the ip settings for the new server when it starts up. However it doesn't seem to be working.  #! /bin/bash
sudo su
Plesk repair web -y
plesk bin ipmanage -u 10.128.0.50 -type shared
plesk bin subscription --update domain.com -ip 10.128.0.50 [/code]

Comment: Unless you really understand GCP and networking, don't modify the DHCP private IP addressing. You can easily create unreachable instances. Managed Instances Groups are not for your use case.

Comment: I'm not modifying the gcp DHCP private settings. I'm modifying Plesk server config to bind to the GCP DHCP private ip settings.for a new instance. btw is there a way to fetch the gcp ip for the new instance to put in a variable in the startup script. Edit. Isee my previous post wording was a bit confusing, but yeah Im trying to put a startup script to change the webserver settings, not the network bindings.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want to host a single VM in Managed Instance Group, you can create an instance template that is bound to specific internal and/or external IP.

You can follow by analogy this example of creation MIGs with fixed IP addresses:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#configuring_the_gateways

As I don't know Plesk, please clarify in your question:

- whether you need to host more than 1 VM in the group
- whether Plask needs to know each individual VM by its both external & internal IP. It seems more natural to point Plesk to the loadbalancer's IP that routes the traffic to one of the VMs in the group.
- why the solution with registration in startup-script didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Use :
plesk bin reconfigurator --autoconfigure

place on startup script of instance template